Navigation title view is automatically hides in iPadOS 18 in elevated TabBar
Navigation title and navBarItems in UITabbarcontroller is hiding automatically when expanding the collpsed splitview in iPad. Upon checking the view hierarchy the title is actully there but not visible in UI
class TabBarController: UITabBarController,UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tabTitles = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"]
        if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
            mode = .tabSidebar
            var tabs = [UITab]()

            for title in tabTitles {
                let tab = UITab(title: title, image: UIImage(systemName: "leaf"), identifier: title, viewControllerProvider: {_ in
                    return self.createSplitViewController()
                })
                tabs.append(tab)
            }
            setTabs(tabs, animated: true)
        }


    }

    func createSplitViewController() -> UISplitViewController {
        let splitViewController = UISplitViewController()
        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary

        let masterViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MasterViewController())
        let detailViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DetailViewController())
        masterViewController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red
        detailViewController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .blue

        splitViewController.viewControllers = [masterViewController, detailViewController]
        return splitViewController
    }
}

This issue persist in UITabBarController's subclass as will as while using UITabBarController as child viewcontroller.https://i.sstatic.net/xF3ekVUi.jpg

I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Find temprory work around bro. primaryViewController(forExpanding:) inside this delegate function i have set the primary nav controller again.

so what are you doing with the nav titles and the nav buttons that are hidden by the new unmovable tab bar? The only way out of this I see is to hide all nav titles when it is showing, but I have buttons that are still hidden - the UISplitViewController primary controller's rightBarButtonItem, and the detail controller's leftBarButtonItem. This is a careless breaking change by Apple.
